# Convert javascript array values to object keys with a default value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm a beginner playing with javascript and react. The problem I'm stuck with is that I have an array consisting of strings, and now I want to convert these strings to keys in an object so I can give them a value.

In other words: I have **["panel1", "panel2"]** and I want to convert it to **{"panel1":false,"panel2":false}**.

After hours of searching, I managed to conjure up a working solution:

```js
const names = ["panel1", "panel2"]
var initialState = {};
Object.keys(names).forEach((name) => initialState = { ...initialState,
  [names[name]]: false
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(initialState))
```

... but looping a function to dynamically expand the object like this seems very unelegant. What would be a better way of doing this? Note that I need my object to be in the same order as the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with yoru code is that the result of `Object.keys(names)` is the array `["0", "1"]` (the *keys* of the array), not the names.

I'd use a [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
const initialState = {};
for (const name of names) {
    initialState[name] = false;
}
```

Or if you can't use ES2015+ features, a `for` loop:

```
var initialState = {};
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    initialState[names[i]] = false;
}
```

Another approach is to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of `[name, value]` arrays from your `names` array, then create the object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
const initialState = Object.fromEntries(names.map(name => [name, false]));
```

`map` is from ES5, and `Object.fromEntriees` is quite new but easily polyfilled for older environments.

Comment: Excellent answer. I learnt a lot! First, that you can set object values like "object[key] = value". If only I'd have figured that out sooner. Why I didn't see that during hours of googling will remain a mystery forever.
Also, you had me google "ES2015" and "transpilation". Apparently it's a good thing that I came in as late as I did :)
Your third example is exactly what I was looking for. Very elegant and readable. I'll use that. But I'm glad  that the other examples taught me more about what goes on "below decks". Thanks.

Comment: @SadBunny - Glad that helped! FWIW, if you're interested in the new stuff starting from ES2015, my new book is out in a couple of months,... :-) See my profile for links if you're interested. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to do this elegantly:

```js
const names = ["panel1", "panel2"]
initialState = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
  acc[name] = false;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(initialState))
```

Comment: I'm with [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) and [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224): `reduce` is overcomplicated for things like this where a simple loop is all that's needed, or a call to a more specific method like `Object.fromEntries`. Nearly every use of `reduce` really should just be a loop, IMHO.

Comment: Your answer works, but to be honest, I don't understand how or why. But it inspires me to look into the reduce thing :) Thanks.